# Does Guile relax restriction on variable name convention by allowing variable names beginning with number?

Tags: scheme, lisp, identifier, guile

For example, It seems that `1+2` can be used in Guile as a variable name:

```
(define 1+2 4)
1+2   ;==>4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was surprised to find that [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-7.html#node_sec_4.2.1) appears not to like identifiers whose names start with a digit (unless they are escaped, perhaps?), if I am reading it properly.  It looks as if the same is true for [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/).  I have not looked at other specifications.

So, if my readings of the specs are correct, then yes, Guile is relaxing this requirement.  However, as I say, I was surprised by this, as, for instance, Racket is perfectly happy with identifiers like `1+`, even when using the `r5rs` language, and such identifiers are very common in other Lisp-family languages (Common Lisp defines `1+` and `1-` in the language itself).

It may however be the case that I am misreading the syntax for *<identifier>* in the specs, or misinterpreting what they mean.

Comment: I found Guile also defines `1+` (a procedure that adding 1 to its argument). The wording of R5RS for identifiers gives me the same impression that it dislikes (if not prohibit) identifiers beginning with a digit.